# Update elements of list on keyentry

Tags: html, jscript

I have been trying to create a list that will update as the user enters values into the text box.

The field separators can be either space, comma, tab or a new line. Multiple occurrences of any separators will be truncated.

I have come up with the following code so far, but it is creating a single li entry for each value separated by space.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myUL").innerHTML = "";
  var node = document.createElement("LI");
  var input = document.getElementById("serverList");
  var val = input.value.split(/[\s,]+/);
  for (i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
    var a = val[i].toUpperCase();
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(a);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(node);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="serverList" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Enter the server list" title="Type in a name">
<ul id="myUL"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new node in each for cycle.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myUL").innerHTML = "";
  var node = document.createElement("LI");
  var input = document.getElementById("serverList");
  var val = input.value.split(/[\s,]+/);

  for (i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
    var a = val[i].toUpperCase();
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(a);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(node);
    node = document.createElement("LI");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="serverList" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Enter the server list" title="Type in a name">
<ul id="myUL"></ul>
```

Comment: Apart from having two createElement("LI"); - creating an unnecessary LI at the end of your loop, what is the difference from my answer?

Comment: It's faster to change for this code. I changed only one line from the original.

Comment: Well. I always try to improve the answer. That teaches the OP to improve how to code.

Answer (score 0):

Move your LI creation inside the loop

```js
document.getElementById("serverList").addEventListener("input",function() {
  var input = this.value;
  var val = input.split(/[\s,]+/);
  document.getElementById("myUL").innerHTML="";
  for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(val[i].toUpperCase());
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(node);
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="serverList" placeholder="Enter the server list" title="Type in a name">
<ul id="myUL"></ul>
```